# How to accept data from client into database

Tags: python, django

How to accept data from the client using a Post request (Login, password, email) with subsequent entry into the database for use when logging in

I used it, but I don't fully understand it correctly or not, most likely not because nothing is written to the database

Views.py

```
class Reqs:
    def __init__(self, user, password, email):
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.email = email


class ReqsEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Reqs):
            return {
                "user": obj.user,
                "password": obj.password,
                "email": obj.email,
            }
        return super().default(obj)


def api_response(request):
    user = request.POST.get("user")
    password = request.POST.get("password")
    email_ = request.POST.get("email")
    data = Data(user, password, email_)
    data.save()
    try:
        return HttpResponse(data, safe=False, encoder=ReqsEncoder)
    except:
        return HttpResponse("G")
```

Comment: you are using django?

Comment: Yes i use django

Comment: You're saving it to database using `Data` class which is nowhere to be see. You can try: 1) printing the data in `api_response`, to see if you're getting it there, 2) saving something else using your `Data` class, perhaps in Django's python shell.

Comment: If we take api_response, it transmits the same thing as in index